# Gecko/Firefox 38 not being recognized as FF on whatsappweb

Tags: c#, vb.net, firefox, whatsapp, geckofx

Im trying to create a simple app which has 1 form that on load goes to web.whatsapp.com i am using GeckoFX 38 (https://bitbucket.org/dherken/geckofx-38.0) and XulRunner 38.0 and my browser is picked up on www.whatsmybrowser.org as Firefox 38

see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QEh4.png

still whatsapp web doesnt see it, see here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlgWO.png

I got a snippet from the geckofx dev who forked the geckofx 38 to help me with my debugging but it was in C# which i do not know. I converted it to VB.net using a tool but i am still not sure how to incorporate this into my app.

C# code:

`GeckoPreferences.User["general.useragent.override"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT " + Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major + "." + Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor + "; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0";
GeckoPreferences.User["extensions.blocklist.enabled"] = false;
GeckoPreferences.User["media.navigator.enabled"] = true;
GeckoPreferences.User["media.navigator.permission.disabled"] = true;`

converted VB.NET code:

`GeckoPreferences.User("general.useragent.override") = ("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT " + Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major & ".") + Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor & "; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"
GeckoPreferences.User("extensions.blocklist.enabled") = False
GeckoPreferences.User("media.navigator.enabled") = True
GeckoPreferences.User("media.navigator.permission.disabled") = True`

how ever he didnt tell me what to import and just pasting this at the top of my form sends declaration errors...if i dim it i get end of statement expected errors.

this is my current code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    GeckoWebBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.web.whatsapp.com")
End Sub
```

End Class

I would really love to have this working any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you simply omitted to include `Gecko` namespace: `Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User("general.useragent.override") = ...`

Comment: im not a code guru yet i think i should import something like `import gecko.gecko...` but i do not know exactly what to import..